# Python with selenium: unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been trying to locate to the following element:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="vm.refreshTimeline()" button-enter="vm.filterRowChange();" ng-model="vm.filterRowValue" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
```

Its is a **search box**.

I tried using class name, xpath, css selector but none of these are working. Still i am getting "**Unable to locate the element**" with the respective attributes.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(1) > div.uiview.ng-scope > div.container.asset-details.ng-scope > div.row.top-buffer > div > div.GanttController > div.input-append.text-center.search_section.ng-scope > input')

driver.find_element_by_class_name('ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty')

  find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')

find_element_by_link_text('Search by Equipment ID or S/N')
```

I even tried using xpath helper to find out the exact xpath, but it is showing an error as:

```
[INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION]
```

Help me to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/input""")`

Answer (score 3):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty[ng-change*='refreshTimeline']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty' and contains(@ng-change,'refreshTimeline')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your time.
I tried in all the ways which you said but still i am unable to locate the element.

Comment: @SaikumarK Your comment doesn't helps me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Lets Set Implicit Wait Timeout:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It maybe take too much time to perform all and it needs to wait in order to guarantee the whole of elements.

For more information:
[Wait Timeout Selenium](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/timeouts/implicit-wait/)